# Location not found for a method reference

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using Roslyn to find method references. 
I have three different projects in the same solution.

UI => BLL => DB

UI calls a method in BLL called GetData and BLL calls a method in DB called GetData

When finding method references in the BLL project the reference in the UI is found.

But when finding reference in the DB project the reference to GetData in BLL is not found (the location property is empty). Any idea why it is only found in the UI project for the BLL project?

Here is the code:

```
foreach (var file in p.Documents)
{
    if (file.Name.StartsWith(".NETFramework") || file.Name.Contains("AssemblyInfo.cs"))
    {
         continue;
    }

    var semanticModel = file.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;

    var classParser = new ClassParser(semanticModel);

    var tree = file.GetSyntaxTreeAsync().Result;

    //  Get public methods
    var methodDeclarations = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes()
        .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
        .Where(method => method.Modifiers.Any(modifier => modifier.Kind() == SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)).ToList();

    var methods = ParseMethods(methodDeclarations, file.Name);
    var methodReferences = new List<MethodDTO>();
    foreach (var method in methods)
    {
        var symbol = GetMethodSymbol(method.Name, semanticModel, file);
        var references = SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(symbol, solution).Result;

        if (references != null && references.Any())
        {
            foreach (var reference in references)
            {
                if (reference.Locations.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var location in reference.Locations)
                    {
                    }
                }                                        
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

There are only warnings in the diagnostics output for the semantic model.

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, are you sure that your semantic model and compilation are correct? You can check it using `SemanticModel.GetDiagnostics(...)` and `Compilation.GetDiagnostics(...)`.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeAlexandria see the attached picture. The diagnostics gives output actually in the DA project. Do you think the warning could be the cause of the problem? I could try and resolve them.

Comment: No, it doesn't. And you need to check diagnostics for BLL project, that must call method from DB, as you describe in the issue.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria you are right the diagnostics from the BLL project gives plenty of errors. Complaining about that the Predefined type System.Object and System.String are not defined or imported

Comment: You lost somewhere a couple of references on the standard assemblies that were depend on the target platform. Try to resolve this errors and check again your issue.

Comment: Yes, well I think this is a known bug in Roslyn. The project and the solution build without a problem. Could be tricky to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was related to the workspace not being properly loaded due to problems with the correct version of msbuild.
[Strange diagnostics errors, prefedined type System... is not defined or imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385005/strange-diagnostics-errors-prefedined-type-system-is-not-defined-or-imported)