# Strange diagnostics errors, prefedined type System... is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am getting Roslyn diagnostics errors when parsing a very basic .NET 4.6 application. The solution files can be downloaded from there 
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/files/2393288/DemoSolution.zip

The dependency tree looks like this:

BLL -> DB

I am getting the following diagnostics errors in the BLL project:

[image]

The solution and projects build fine, still Roslyn gives these errors. Maybe the errors are misleading and I need to configure the projects in someway? Any idea how I can resolve these errors?

Here is the code used for parsing the files:

```
var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    ["DesignTimeBuild"] = "true",
                    ["CheckForSystemRuntimeDependency"] = "true"
                };
                var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create(properties);

                workspace.WorkspaceFailed += (sender, args) =>
                {

                };
                workspace.LoadMetadataForReferencedProjects = true;

Solution solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(SolutionFilePath).Result;               
                    foreach (var p in solution.Projects)
                    {   
                        foreach (var file in p.Documents)
                        {
      var semanticModel = file.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;

                        var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(file.FilePath);
                    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation",
                        new[] { semanticModel.SyntaxTree }, new[] { mscorlib });

                    var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(semanticModel.SyntaxTree);
                    var declarationDiagnistics = model.Compilation.GetDeclarationDiagnostics(CancellationToken.None);
                    var parseDiagnostics = model.Compilation.GetParseDiagnostics(CancellationToken.None);
                    var allDiagnostics = model.Compilation.GetDiagnostics(CancellationToken.None);
                    var methodBodyDiagnostics = model.Compilation.GetMethodBodyDiagnostics(CancellationToken.None);

                                  }
                }
```

Subscriping to the workspace.workspaceFailed event results in the following error:

> Msbuild failed when processing the file 'MYPATH\BLL.csproj' with
>   message: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:
>   (1656, 5): The "GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask" task could not
>   be instantiated from the assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.Build.Tasks.dll".
>   Please verify the task assembly has been built using the same version
>   of the Microsoft.Build.Framework assembly as the one installed on your
>   computer and that your host application is not missing a binding
>   redirect for Microsoft.Build.Framework. Unable to cast object of type
>   'NuGet.Build.Tasks.GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask' to type
>   'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask'. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:
>   (1656, 5): The "GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask" task has been
>   declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the
>   spelling of the task name and the assembly name.

Comment: please check - Remove bin and obj and rebuild. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224206/predefined-type-system-object-is-not-defined-or-imported-net-4-6

Comment: Hi @Ajay2707 thanks for your suggestion. But even if I removed the bin and obj folder from the solution I still get the same errors. Any other suggestions I could try?

Comment: can you check other option suggested on that link?

Comment: @Ajay2707 so when I remove the DB reference from the BLL I don´t get the errors anymore. So I tried creating a new DB project with nothing but the empty class1.cs file in it. Readding the reference to the BLL still gives the same errors.

Comment: Hi @Ajay2707 I attached the solution files and the code used for parsing the files. Could you test it as well? The code is very basic just for testing. Thanks!

Comment: You get these kind of errors when Roslyn doesn't have a reference to mscorlib.dll

Comment: Hi @HansPassant do you mean I should a add a reference to mscorlib.dll in the roslyn solution. If I try to do this I get the error The ActiveX type library 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb' was exported from a .NET assembly and cannot be added as a reference.

Comment: Wrong file, mscorlib.dll, not .tlb.  Roslyn needs reference assemblies to compile/analyze code, just like you need them in the References node of a project.  mscorlib.dll is fairly special, it doesn't show up in a project's Reference node because it is always needed.  Your demo project is not helpful to repro this problem, it is missing the Roslyn code.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant, thanks for your help. So should I browse to the dll file under references or simply copy the file to the output folder? If I try to browse I get the error dialog ---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
A reference to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system. It's a bit strange to me why this doesn't simply work out of the box without having to references dll's other than in the Roslyn nuget package

Comment: No.  Google "site:stackoverflow.com roslyn mscorlib reference" for similar questions.

Comment: Thanks, I found an example code where the mscorlib is included in the creation of the semantic model and I updated the example code above accordingly. Nonetheless I continue to get the same errors :s

Comment: `var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(file.FilePath);` it would not be a references to the `mscorlib` and `object` may contains in the different assemblies for different target platform. As you target `net46` you can try: `var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);`

Comment: Hi @GeorgeAlexandria thanks yes thats probably the right way to do it and this is what I initially did but it did not work either.

Comment: Did you try to subscribe on `workspace.WorkspaceFailed` event before try to open solution?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeAlexandria you where right the workspaceFailed resulted in the error above. Do you think this has something to do with VS2017 maybe I should try to run this in VS2015?

Comment: 1) You should post what is the `workspace` and how did you get him 2) You can post failed error to)

Comment: hi I posted the error as part of the issue. what do you mean what is the workdpace?

Comment: hi @GeorgeAlexandria I added the workspace initialization to the code sample above. Do you see anything I am missing from there?

Comment: 1) I were surprised. Why do you try to create `Compilation` `var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create...` when you can just receive it from `semanticModel.Compilation`? 2) About workspace, it can not correct determine the version of msbuild that should use.To fix it you can try to add the correct binding redirects in app.config or try to [un]install msbuild from GAC

Comment: Hi @GeorgeAlexandria and thanks for your help. Do you have an example for a binding redirect for msbuild? Regarding 1. I used to do it this way but then I changed it so I could specify the properties.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2369#issuecomment-353674937

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this finally solved it:

1. Added the microsoft.build redirects as suggested by @GeorgeAlexandria 
   http://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2369#issuecomment-353674937
2. Cleared the Microsoft.Build.* from the output bin folder
3. Added the Microsoft.Build.Locator as a reference
4. Added the line MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults() above the workspace code.

Source:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/26029#issuecomment-380164421